# Best LDAP server to be used with Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ldap

I am going to build a Web application that will interact with LDAP.
I was looking over a list of LDAP servers but could not found that which one will be best and easy in use.

- IBM Tivoli Directory Server
- Active Directory
- Sun One Directory Server
- Open DS (now called OpenDJ)
- [OpenLDAP](http://openLDAP.org)
- [UnboundID Directory Server](http://www.unboundid.com/products/directory-server.php)

  I am using Websphere with framework Spring MVC. Mostly I will search, add, update in LDAP. There can be any other server that you might use and found useful.

Comment: If you're looking for open source software, then your choice is down to OpenDJ or OpenLDAP. OpenDJ is definitely easier to get started with and is very complete in term of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to choose a server product without specifying a list of constraints and requirements. The only requirement listed is that the server supports Java EE, which is meaningless.

OpenLDAP is not listed. Sun ONE Directory Server no longer exists, what was the Sun DSEE is now bundled at Oracle. [UnboundID Directory Server](http://www.unboundid.com/products/directory-server.php) is not listed.

Do you need:

- certain request controls, features or extensions?
- willing to pay for commercial product, if so, what is the budget?
- proxy required?
- API required?

There are many other things that could be listed, but the meaning should be clear: a list of requirements and constraints is necessary to make the most correct, well-fitted decision (I used to work at a place that chose products based on whether they were written in Python, which is, of course, completely absurd).